# Reference request: Cohomology of Elliptic Curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, galois-theory, class-field-theory

Is it true that the group
$$H^1(Gal(K^{ab}/K)/\mu_{\nu}(Gal(K_{\nu}^{ab}/K_{\nu})),E_{p^n})$$
is always p-divisible? Or are there any conditions which, when satisfied, guarantee its p-divisibility?
Here, $()^{ab}$ denotes the maximal Abelian extension of a field, $K_{\nu}$ is the localization of a field number field $K$ at a finite prime $\nu$, $\mu_{\nu}:Gal(K_{\nu}^{ab}/K_{\nu})\rightarrow Gal(K^{ab}/K)$ is induced by the injection $K\rightarrow K_{\nu}$ and $E_{p^n}$ are the $p^n$-torsion points of a (non-singular) elliptic curve $E$ defined over $K$.

I am specifically interested in the cases

(A.) $E$ has bad reduction at $\nu$.

(B.) $\nu$ divides $p$.

(C.) None of the above, and $E(K_{\nu})_{p^{\infty}}=E(\overline{K_{\nu}})_{p^{n}}$

Can somebody give me a good reference?

I am not an expert on the subject, so please have mercy on my soul.

Comment: Why is the image of $\mu_\nu$ a normal subgroup of ${\rm Gal}(K^{\rm ab}|K)$ ? Sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Because $Gal (K^{ab}/K) $ is Abelian.

Comment: As the group is killed by $p^n$, it can only be $p$-divisible if it is trivial.

Comment: The group in question only makes sense if all poitns in $E_{p^n}$ are defined over $K^{ab}$. So you have to be in a rather particular situation unless they are already defined over $K$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich: The field $L=K ([p^{-n}]E (K)) $ (i.e. the field obtained by adjoining the components of all $p^n$th roots of elements of E (K)), over which all $p^n $-torsion points are certainly defined, is an Abelian extension of $K $, c.f. Joseph Silverman, The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Prop. VIII.1.5.

Comment: No. *IF* the $m$-torsion points are defined over $K$, then all $Q\in E(\bar{K})$ with $mQ\in E(K)$ are defined over an abelian extension. -- Instead the extension adjoining all $m$-torsion points is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$. It is very often equal to the full (very non-abelian) group.